# evaluation integral $\int 2x\cdot \sin(x^2) \ dx$ = ? solved by two diffrent ways who is correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, alternative-proof

$\int 2x\cdot \sin(x^2)  \ dx$ = ?

My friend and I solved this question in different ways does it matter how we solve it?

I tried this way

$\int uv'= uv - \int u'v \rightarrow u=2x \ ,   u'=2  \ , v'=\sin(x^2)  \ , v=-\cos(x^2)/2 \ ,$

$\Rightarrow \int 2x\cdot \sin(x^2)= -2x\cdot \frac{\cos(x^2)}{2}-\int2\cdot -\frac{\cos(x^2)}{2} $
$= -x\cdot \cos(x^2)+\int \cos(x^2) $
$= -x\cdot \cos(x^2)+\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x} $

his solution was

$t=x^2 \ \rightarrow dt=2x\ dx \rightarrow dx=\frac{dt}{2x} $

$\int 2x\cdot \sin(x^2) \ dx =\int 2x\cdot \sin(t) \frac{dt}{2x}=\int \sin(t)=-\cos(x^2) $

Comment: Your friend's is wrong, why $sin(t)$ ? Shouldn't it be $sin(\sqrt{t})$ ?

Comment: o sorry i miss write it one second

Comment: Use \sin to produce $\sin$. Similarly for $\cos$.

Comment: does one of the solutions is better than the other ?

Comment: is there any problem, with the solutions or they are both equal?

Comment: $v =  - \cos (x^2 )/2 \Rightarrow v' = \sin (x^2 )x \ne \sin (x^2 )$ by the chain rule.

Comment: The derivative of $-\cos (x^2)$ is not $\sin(x^2)$

Comment: thanks ! i now understand the problem with my solution thank you !

Comment: Your solution using integration by parts is incorrect, while your friend's solution using u-substitution is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His method is actually much simpler than integration by parts.  He did it by simple substitution with $t = x^2, dt = 2x \ dx$ to get $\int \sin t \ dt = - \cos t + C = -\cos(x^2) +C.$

You want to find the simplest method in integrating a function, but unfortunately, integrating this function by parts is a nightmare (and it didn't result in the original function when it's differentiated).